# Show alias coefficient of Plackett Burman design equals $r_{ij}=\frac{c_{1i}'c_{2j}}{N}$

Tags: probability, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, experiment-design

Consider a Plackett Burman design with N rows and let $\beta_{1}$ be the of the regression coeﬃcients corresponding to the main eﬀects and let $\beta_{2}$ be the vector of the regression coeﬃcients corresponding to the two-factor interactions (assume without loss of generality that the constant term $\beta_{0}$ = 0). Let $c_{1i}$ denote the vector of contrast coeﬃcients for the ith main eﬀect and let $c_{2j}$ denote the vector of contrast coeﬃcients for the jth two- factor interaction. Show that the alias coeﬃcient equals

$\large r_{ij}=\frac{c_{1i}'c_{2j}}{N}$

Under what condition on $c_{1i}$ and $c_{2j}$ are the two eﬀects not aliased with each other?

Attempt: I have a rough understand as to how to do this problem. I know that the alias matrix is equal to:

$(X_1'X_1)^{-1}X_1X_2$

I know that if two effects are aliases of each other, then their contrast vectors are identical, except for a possible change of sign. If two effects are not aliased with each other, then their contrast vectors are orthogonal to each other.